# Writing portable js upload code(JS code works on desktop and fails on mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok am working on a laravel web project, I have written this code(which I learned online) to upload video and photos. This code works fine when uploading pictures because they are light. But when it gets to videos it works fine for light videos but tries to freeze the browser for videos above 30MB. The most annoying part is that when I tried uploading(picture or video) from mobile the device complained 'Failed to complete operation due to low memory' the fact that this code freezes the browser for heavy videos and and complains of memory on mobile means its not good enough(portable). Please I will appreciate having a better snippet of code to do the job(jQuery welcomed).

Here is what I have

```js
function uploadPhoto(url, photo) {

var token = $('#token').val();
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('photo', photo);
formData.append('_token', token);
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener('load', completeHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener('error', errorHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener('abort', abortHandler, false);
ajax.open('POST', url);
ajax.send(formData);
  }

function uploadVideo() {
    var route = $('#uploadUrl').val();
    var token = $('#token').val();
    var video = document.getElementById('postVideo').files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('video', video);
    formData.append('_token', token);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener('load', completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener('error', errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener('abort', abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open('POST', route);
    ajax.send(formData);
  }
```

The functions in the event listeners have code to take appropriate actions like displaying a progress bar..Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having based off the error message `'Failed to complete operation due to low memory'` is that you are specifically running out of RAM (or allotted RAM for that application/instance on mobile).

[Uploading Techniques in Javascript](http://creativejs.com/tutorials/advanced-uploading-techniques-part-1/)

you see the issue with upload the 30MB file is that it needs to load the entire file into memory, I'm not sure about the exact details of who owns those memory addresses weather it be application restriction so Chrome or the device itself. Your best bet is to do chunk uploading, It has many benefits and will now allow you to only have to take up 1MB (or whatever size you want) to be chunked at. This allows the upload to be smoother as it no longer needs to have the entire video loaded.

It's a pretty big article/solution so I wont be adding code into the answer since there are many pieces to it, but I have used that as a base to implement the chunking uploading. This will solve your issue on all browsers/devices.

-- as a side note you could always limit how much is uploaded so this doesn't occur but if big uploads is what you are trying to achieve this is a good point to start.

Comment: Ok thanks @Andrei M. I will take a detail look of the resource you provided